# Need help on my circuit

Tags: circuit-analysis, circuit-design

This is my circuit that was made on tinkercad. The issue is that 7408 is blowing up every time when 2 switches are on but three switches it works. I just needed advice on how to fix this. At the bottom of the page is where the truth table and diagram is.

Boolean equation is AB + AC + BC (AB is Orange, AC is green, BC is light blue)

Material: 74HC08, 74HC32, led, three switches, power supply and lastly 470 ohm resistor.

[image]

This is a picture of the circuit when it accepts 2 inputs only.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Could you try adding an actual schematic? A breadboard is hard to follow...

Comment: Not going to try reading that non-schematic.

Comment: @Brian Drummond   I posted it at the bottom of the page

Comment: @Ron Beyer Yes I post it at the bottom with a truth table.

Comment: Put pin numbers on the schematic, so we can compare the schematic with the actual wiring.  The actual wiring does not match your schematic.  Not directly related, but unused inputs of CMOS gates MUST be connected to either Vcc or Gound, otherwise the gate input circuit may pass excessive current and damage the part.

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE, Jag. It's a good idea if the title of the question gives a better description of the problem. Almost all questions on this site are about circuits so your title fails in that regard. In this case something to the effect of "CMOS logic circuit burning quad AND chip" might have been more useful. You can bear it in mind for future questions.

Answer (score 4):

It appears that you have three outputs of the 74HC08 connected to pin 1 of the 74HC32 - you MUST NOT connect multiple outputs CMOS logic parts together!

A schematic diagram, showing the individual gates of the ICs, would make it much easier to diagnose the problem without having to find and study the datasheets for each part.

Comment: Thank you, make sense

Comment: "you MUST NOT connect multiple outputs CMOS logic parts together!"  Well you *can*, but only in the same vein as drag racing in reverse gear or such things.

Answer (score 3):

You have all three 74HC08 outputs wired together.

You can't connect outputs together, it will blow up.

Imagine that one output wants to set the output to 5V, and other output wants to set the output to 0V, so there is large current flowing.

Comment: oh okay thank you.